# Every Subring of Z[x] has Ascending Chain Condition on Principal Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Please help me to prove that every subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$ has Ascending Chain Condition on Principal ideals.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A\subset\Bbb Z[x]$ be a subring and suppose that $A$ doesn't satisfy ACCP, so there exists $f_1A\subset f_2A\subset\cdots\subset f_nA\subset\cdots$ a strictly ascending chain of principal ideals in $A$. We get $\cdots f_n\mid\cdots\mid f_2\mid f_1$ (in $A$) and therefore $\deg f_1\ge \deg f_2\ge\cdots\ge \deg f_n\ge\cdots$. Then there exists an $m\ge 1$ such that $\deg f_m=\deg f_{m+1}=\cdots$. Since $f_{m+1}\mid f_m$ there is $a_{m+1}\in\Bbb Z$, $a_{m+1}\ne -1,0,1$, such that $f_m=a_{m+1}f_{m+1}$, and this shows that $a_{m+1}$ divides the leading coefficient of $f_m$. Continuing this way we find an infinite sequence $(a_i)_{i\ge m+1}$ of integral numbers different from $-1,0,1$ such that $a_{m+1}\cdots a_{m+j}$ divides the leading coefficient of $f_m$ for all $j\ge 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why writing up a direct proof as a contradiction? (I know that this happens all the time ...)

Answer (score 0):

start with a principal ideal $I_0$ generated by a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. 
Say $p$ has degree n. 
Now consider an ascending chain of principal ideals 
$$
I_0\subset I_1\subset I_2\subset\ldots
$$
and their corresponding elements. Prove that after there exists $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the generator of $I_j$ has degree which is strictly smaller than $n$.

Now proceed by induction.

Comment: @Waqas In the induction step, you will need to prove that $\Bbb Z$ statisfies ACC. So that might be a good place to start.

Comment: yes i can prove that Z satisfies ACC. What if i am working particularly on a subring of Z[x] with f(1/2) always an integer? How to proceed in this case?

Comment: @Waqas That subring is not an ideal. The reason is that given such an $f$, there is always some $n$ such that $x^nf(x)$ is a polynomial which doesn't evaluate to an integer at $1/2$. So I believe you can't apply ACC in that case.

Comment: @Arthur I may be wrong but to apply ACCP we need prime ideals of this subring, it is not necessary for the subring to be ideal itself